# Strong Link - Weak Link in software security

Tags: security, principles

Give me an example on how I could apply the [Strong Link - Weak Link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_link_weak_link) principle in designing a security component for a piece of software. Is there such a concept of "weak" modules in software security, where in case of an attack these will deliberately fail first, and determine the impossibility of the attacker to access and compromise any other, more sensitive data?

Comment: I think this may be the first question on SO related to nuclear weapon design

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing that can happen accidentally is to fail (as DoS) under a dictionary attack. Generally you would want to throttle, which I guess is a weaker version of weak module.